# I have a feature model (in xml format). Is there a way to generate java classes for any given feature model when a required feature is traversed?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse

I have tried reading the XML file using JAXB but it only reads the first-level elements. I also do not know how to go about generating the java classes for each of the required features in the XML file. Here is a sample feature model that I am working with and the output I have obtained from reading the file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
        <featureModel>
            <struct>
                <and abstract="true" mandatory="true" name="SvgMapApp">
                    <feature name="L2Build"/>
                    <and abstract="true" mandatory="true" name="Layers">
                        <feature name="ColorRegion"/>
                        <feature name="Relief"/>
                        <feature name="Rivers"/>
                        <feature name="Lakes"/>
                        <feature name="PopCircle"/>
                    </and>
                    <and abstract="true" mandatory="true" name="Legends">
                        <and abstract="true" name="Controls">
                            <feature name="Navigator"/>
                            <feature name="ReliefControls"/>
                            <feature name="RiverControls"/>
                            <feature name="LakeControls"/>
                            <feature name="PopCircleControls"/>
                            <feature name="CoordinateDisplay"/>
                        </and>
                        <and abstract="true" name="Stats1">
                            <feature name="AgeChart"/>
                            <feature name="StatsMedianAge"/>
                            <feature name="EthnicBarChart"/>
                            <feature name="EthnicPieChart"/>
                        </and>
                        <and abstract="true" name="Stats2">
                            <feature name="StatsSex"/>
                            <feature name="StatsHouseholds"/>
                            <feature name="StatsPopulation"/>
                        </and>
                        <feature hidden="true" name="Legend"/>
                    </and>
                    <feature hidden="true" mandatory="true" name="USStates"/>
                    <feature mandatory="true" name="Base"/>
                </and>
            </struct>
            <constraints>
                <rule>
                    <imp>
                        <var>PopCircleControls</var>
                        <var>PopCircle</var>
                    </imp>
                </rule>
                <rule>
                    <imp>
                        <var>ReliefControls</var>
                        <var>Relief</var>
                    </imp>
                </rule>
                <rule>
                    <imp>
                        <var>RiverControls</var>
                        <var>Rivers</var>
                    </imp>
                </rule>
                <rule>
                    <imp>
                        <var>LakeControls</var>
                        <var>Lakes</var>
                    </imp>
                </rule>
                <rule>
                    <imp>
                        <var>Controls</var>
                        <var>Legend</var>
                    </imp>
                </rule>
                <rule>
                    <imp>
                        <var>Stats1</var>
                        <var>Legend</var>
                    </imp>
                </rule>
                <rule>
                    <imp>
                        <var>Stats2</var>
                        <var>Legend</var>
                    </imp>
                </rule>
                <rule>
                    <imp>
                        <var>L2Build</var>
                        <not>
                            <var>EthnicBarChart</var>
                        </not>
                    </imp>
                </rule>
            </constraints>
            <comments>
                <c> this turns panel a off</c>
                <c> this turns panel a off</c>
                <c>Layers { tab }</c>
                <c>Legends { out="" }</c>
                <c>Controls { tab }</c>
                <c>Stats1 { tab }</c>
                <c>Stats2 { tab }</c>
            </comments>
        </featureModel>
```

I would like to autogenerate the model classes, but here are the classes I have worked with and the output I obtained:

FeatureModel.java

```
public class FeatureModel {
    
     @XmlElement(name="struct")
     private Struct struct;

       

        public Struct getStruct ()
        {
            return struct;
        }

        public void setStruct (Struct struct)
        {
            this.struct = struct;
        }

       .....
        
}
```

Struct.java

```
public class Struct {
    
    @XmlElement(name="and")

    private And and[];
    
    public And[] getAnd ()
    {
        return and;
    }

    public void setAnd (And[] and)
    {
        this.and = and;
    }

    .........
    
    
}
```

Alt.java

```
public class Alt {
    @XmlElement(name="feature")
    private Feature[] feature;
    
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

   
    @XmlAttribute
    private String mandatory;

    public Feature[] getFeature ()
    {
        return feature;
    }

    public void setFeature (Feature[] feature)
    {
        this.feature = feature;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    
    public String getMandatory ()
    {
        return mandatory;
    }

    public void setMandatory (String mandatory)
    {
        this.mandatory = mandatory;
    }

    ...........
}
```

And.java

```
public class And {
    
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;
    
    @XmlAttribute
    private String mandatory;
    

    @XmlElement(name="feature")
    private Feature[] feature;
     
    @XmlElement(name="or")
    private Or or;

    @XmlElement(name="alt")
    private Alt alt;
    
    public String getName ()
        {
            return name;
        }

    public void setName (String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }
    public Feature[] getFeature ()
        {
            return feature;
        }

    public void setFeature (Feature[] feature)
        {
            this.feature = feature;
        }

    public Or getOr ()
    {
        return or;
    }

    public void setOr (Or or)
    {
        this.or = or;
    }

    public Alt getAlt ()
    {
        return alt;
    }

    public void setAlt (Alt alt)
    {
        this.alt = alt;
    }

  
    public String getMandatory ()
    {
        return mandatory;
    }

    public void setMandatory (String mandatory)
    {
        this.mandatory = mandatory;
    }

    .......
        
}
```

Or.java

```
public class Or {
    
    @XmlElement(name="feature")
    private Feature[] feature;
    
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;

    public Feature[] getFeature ()
    {
        return feature;
    }

    public void setFeature (Feature[] feature)
    {
        this.feature = feature;
    }

    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName (String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    ......
}
```

Feature.java

```
public class Feature {
    
    @XmlAttribute
     private String name;

        public String getName ()
        {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName (String name)
        {
            this.name = name;
        }

        ...............
}
```

Here is my output:
FeatureModel [struct = Struct [and = [And Root = SvgMapApp, mandatory = true, feature = [Feature [name = L2Build], Feature [name = USStates], Feature [name = Base]] [alt = null, or = null]]]]

Comment: Have you tried creating an xsd file for the xml and autogenerate the model classes?

Comment: Yes, I have tried using an online tool to create the XSD file. But what I really need is autogenerating the model classes from any given feature model (in xml format).

Comment: Yeah that structure looks recursive, you'll need to manually adjust an xsd if you try to generate it automatically.

Comment: @daniu Can you please throw more light on how I could go about manually adjusting the file? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As for adjusting the generated Java code, look at what exactly each element can contain and what is missing. For instance, the `and` elements in the xml contain either `feature`s or `and`s (or both); in the `And` class, only a member for a list of `Feature`s is present, so add the `and`s manually.

```
public class And {
    
    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;
    
    @XmlAttribute
    private String mandatory;
    

    @XmlElement(name="feature")
    private Feature[] feature;
     
    @XmlElement(name="or")
    private Or or;

    @XmlElement(name="alt")
    private Alt alt;

    // added
    @XmlElement(name="and")
    private And[] and;
}
```

This should also cover the `and`s in the deeper nested levels. Looking at your output, the `and`s are exactly what are missing. I would also assume several `or`s and `alt`s are possible (so those should be array fields), but those aren't present in the xml at all, so I guess they come from another file - you'll have to see for yourself how they fit in.

The `feature` seems to always have a name, but also a `hidden` and `mandatory` attribute sometimes, so add those to `Feature`.

Comment: You are right. The "and"s are what were missing. Introducing it solved the nested level problem. Thanks.